# using for loop when scripting bash shell in linux

Tags: shell, loops, for-loop

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Id,Name,Amount,TS > lfs.csv
```

I want to insert values that will match the columns I created (as above in the script) , I want for example to insert: 56,"Danny",579,311413567
I want to be able to insert it using 'FOR' loop which will insert values without stopping but to change the values for each insert

Comment: I will be using external text file which will hold the data or I will invoke random data from the bash script which will be changed in this way:
in the iteration it will be:
56,"Danny",579,311413567
the next iteration will be:
57,"Danny_1",580,311413568

and so on and on till:
n,"Danny_n",n,n

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show what you have as input and what you want to output? Now your question is quite vague, and I'm sure you don't mean you actually want to output random values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More detail would be useful what you like to achieve exactly, so I made a infinite for loop which put line into the csv incremented numbers you provide by $i. ( I cannot make comment yet to ask you )

Update:
I still using a infinite loop to get a number counting up to the endless, and using a variable (u_id) to count from 1 to 100 then reset it back to 1 if it is reach 100.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Id,Name,Amount,TS,unique_ID' > lfs.csv

u_id=0

for (( id=1 ; ;id++ ))
do
[[ $u_id == 100 ]] && (( u_id = 1 )) || (( u_id +=1 ))

        echo $id",Danny_"$id","$id","$id","$u_id >> lfs.csv

done
```

If you like to start Amount and TS from bigger number you can do that by modifing $id to $(( id + 50000 )) like:

```
echo $id",Danny_"$id","$(( id + 300 ))","$(( id + 50000 ))","$u_id >> lfs.csv
```

Comment: I want to add another column which will be the primary key I want the loop to iterate from 1 to 100 and when it get to 100 it will start to iterate again from 1 to 100 sorry for changing my question but I just got it from my direct manager how can I do that?

Comment: The primary key should be unique? So record should look like this?

1-∞,1-100,Name,Amount,TS

If you could provide the text file format from the other data (Name,Amount,TS ) came would be help me to make the loops echo, or how should I handle them?

Comment: Id , Name, Amount, TS, unique_ID - Id should be running forever as well as name,amount and TS, unique_id should be running from 1-100 and when it gets to 100 it should repeat again from 1-100...Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope it will suit your need now.

Comment: Yes thank you but just one thing I nerd that all other variables will be running forever except one that will run till it get to 100 when it does it will be 1 again and will be run till 100 again.

Comment: Thanks I will try it and will update big thank you for your help!